# installing ecobee SmartThermostat with Voice Control on older home

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

[image][image][image][image]I recently purchased the most recent ecobee Smart Thermostat with Voice Control.  The existing thermostat needs to be updated.  However, I'm not sure if I'm able to install this without installing the power extender kit (PEK).  The existing wiring is attached.  The current thermostat is a free NV energy smart thermostat which is shown.  Please let me know if I'm able to install this, preferably without the extender kit, thanks.[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the wiring at the furnace/air-handler end of the situation please?

Answer (score 1):

Based on that picture, you will not need a PEK, but you'll have to check on the furnace/AC as @ThreePhaseEel has pointed out.

You have:

> Power (Red) (R)
>
> Heat Call (Black) (W)
>
> Fan (Green) (G)
>
> Cooling (Blue) (Y)
>
> Common (White) (C)

Matching those up to the ecobee labels should be pretty easy.

Comment: Since the installer used non-standard colors, be very careful about labeling this and hooking it back up to the new thermostat.  Ignore any colors mentioned in the manual and pay attention to the letter codes.

Comment: Hello, I'm still unsure how to install this.  The wall plate diagram is attached.  Could you please match the colors with the corresponding letter, e.g., c terminal with white wire, etc.?  It'd be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use the picture:  unscrew all the terminal screws.  Remove the plate. Put the Ecobee plate on the wall, and route all of the wires through.  Connect each color wire to the same 'name' on the ecobee.

Comment: Hello, I installed this several months ago and it turned on; however, when I tried to turn on the ac cooling, the vents only blew out hot air instead of cold.  I have attached a picture of the wiring.  I heeded the advice of the previous post but apparently something is hooked up wrong.  I’d appreciate input, thanks